# Creating a measurement bar in WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, controls

I'm working on a measurement system and I need to represent to the user the measure level in a nice graphical way. I designed a measurement bar in Photoshop and I'm now trying to implement it in WPF.

Does anyone have an idea of how to best implement such control? I though it should have a max / min and according to the bounded value it will move by using a transform, that's the easier part, but the actual graphics are tricky here...

The control I was thinking about looks like this:

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will most likely need the ProgressBar control.

Or make your own one from scratch, just by [searching in google this website](http://kishor-naik-dotnet.blogspot.co.uk/2011/03/wpf-custom-progress-bar-in-wpf.html) showing how to create your own custom control comes up as the first listing

http://kishor-naik-dotnet.blogspot.co.uk/2011/03/wpf-custom-progress-bar-in-wpf.html

Comment: Thanks! I don't know how I didn't think about reusing the ProgressBar control